# datastax, Spark , and MLLIB

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have two questions:

1. It seems that the Spark that comes with the Datastax enterprise does not support Spark's MLLIB, fully. This leads to considerable limitations in the algorithms that can be run using Datastax Spark. Does Datastax have any plans to fully support MLLIB in the near future? If yes, when?
2. Is it possible to run an Apache Spark (not use the Datastax Spark) in a cluster along side of Datastax Cassandra and communicate between them? If yes, what is the best practice for doing so? I could not find any documentation on this and I will appreciate if you could direct me towards it (if any exists).

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: you should make 2 questions out of this one.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd imagine yes.
2. Have Spark worker nodes run on the same boxes as Cassandra (OLTP) nodes. Have a separate Spark Master (assuming standalone mode). If failover is required, run another Spark Master with Zookeeper. Check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html for details. This is essentially the same as running apache spark and apache cassandra together. The spark cassandra connector https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector is locality aware, and as such, there's tremendous benefit in running spark workers and cassandra on the same nodes. You do lose automatic fault tolerance that you'd get from DSE for spark, and you have to set everything up, but it works fine. For example, I'm using apache spark and apache cassandra together in production for a while. A benefit is you don't have to wait for DSE to catch up when new versions of spark are released.